# Matlab: error message "Matrix Dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab, matrix

In the code, the "createbook" and "displaybook" are functions Ive created and I know that these work and are not the issue. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it. If you need more information, just leave a comment and Ill get back to you

```
Books = [];

Choice = input('What would you like to do: ','s'); 

while (Choice)

   if Choice == 'add book'

      Title = input('Enter the title: ','s');
      Author = input('Enter the author: ','s');
      Pages = input('Enter the number of pages: ');

      New = createbook(Title, Author, Pages);

      displaybook(New);

      fprintf('%s has been added to the library\n',New)

      Books = [Books New];

   elseif Choice == 'quit'

      disp('PROGRAM END')

      return;  

   end

   Choice = input('What would you like to do: ','s'); 

end
```

Comment: use `strcmp` for comparing strings - and learn how to use debugger

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the ["how to ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43610414/edit) to include *at least* the following: the specific error message; the line number on which the error is reported; the Matlab or Octave version you are using; and what the dimensions of some of the relevant matrices are.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Also, see some of the "Related" questions on the right --- maybe one of those will help.  -------->

Answer (score 0):

Use strcmp instead of (==). The reason is that when you write in Matlab the statement if ('string1' == 'string2'), it returns a boolean vector, which checks for each index i if (str1[i] == str2[i]). If the two strings have different lengths it will throw an exception